# Knockoutjs Multiselect shows index instead of text value when using viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, viewbag

I'm using a viewbag to load the options for a multi-select list.  However, when I do that I'm getting a 1-based index instead of the actual text value.

```
<td> @Html.DropDownList("MAMUserGroupName", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.MAMUserGroupsList, new { multiple = "multiple", data_bind = "selectedOptions:MAMUserGroups" })</td>
```

Here's the viewModel:

```
    var viewModel = new UserModel([
    {
        id: ko.observable(""), firstName: ko.observable(""), lastName: ko.observable(""),MAMUserGroups: ko.observable()
    }
]);
```

When the value is selected and I call the knockout save function, the value is 1, 2, and/or 3, instead of the actual text value; in this case "Group1", "Group2", "Group3"

When I do it the standard way of hard-coded options like here it works as expected: [Knockout selectedOptions example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html).  But in my case I need to load it from the viewbag.

Answer (score 0):

The @Html.DropdownList is a server side rendering of the list and knockoutjs is a client side rendering of the list and the two do not know about each other.  What you need to do is either render the list to a javascript array on they page, or retrieve it via Ajax/fetch from the server then render it client side.  So using your code examples, i would be filling you knockoutjs view model with the data you need. something like the following.

```js
var PageModel = function(data) {
  var users = ko.observableArray();
  var userGroups = ko.observableArray();

  var mappedUsers = data.Users.map(function(user) {
    return {
      id: ko.observable(user.id),
      firstName: ko.observable(user.firstName),
      lastName: ko.observable(user.lastName),
      mameUserGroups: ko.observableArray()
    };
  });

  users(mappedUsers);

  var mappedGroups = data.MAMUserGroups.map(function(item) {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      name: item.name
    };
  });

  userGroups(mappedGroups);


  return {
    users: users,
    userGroups: userGroups
  };

};


ko.applyBindings(new PageModel({
  //****** Data loaded here ******
  Users: [{
    id: 1,
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "user 1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "user 2"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "user 3"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "user 4"
  }],
  MAMUserGroups: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "User Group 1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "User Group 2"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "User Group 3"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "User Group 4"
  }]
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
      <td>
        <select data-bind="options: $parent.userGroups, selectedOptions: mameUserGroups, optionsText: 'name' " size='5' multiple='true'> </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<ul data-bind="foreach: users">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: mameUserGroups">
      <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<!--
<script type="text/javascript">
// Render the data on the page server side to then be used client side
  $().ready(function(){
    
    var users = @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Users)));
    var mamUserGroups =  @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.mamUserGroups)));
  });
</script>
-->
```

**EDIT Ajax implementation**

This is one way to do it.  probably more code than is needed but i like to break things up into separate area of responsibility.  If you try running this snippet from here what you will get is an error alert and a finished alert for the users and user groups.

```js
var app = window.app || {};


app.modelMap = (function() {
  function userMap(user) {
    return {
      id: ko.observable(user.id),
      firstName: ko.observable(user.firstName),
      lastName: ko.observable(user.lastName),
      mameUserGroups: ko.observableArray()
    };
  }

  function userGroupMap(userGroup) {
    return {
      id: userGroup.id,
      name: userGroup.name
    };
  }


  return {
    userMap: userMap,
    userGroupMap: userGroupMap
  }
})();

app.data = (function() {
  function getUserGroups() {
    return $.get("<MAMUSerGroup_URL_HERE>").then(function(data) {
        alert("successfully retrieved user group data");
        return data.map(app.modelMap.userGroupMap);
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
      })
      .always(function() {
        alert("finished");
      });
  };

  function getUsers() {
    return $.get("<Users_URL_HERE>").then(function(data) {
        alert("successfully retrieved user data");
        return data.map(app.modelMap.userMap);
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
      })
      .always(function() {
        alert("finished");
      });
  }
  return {
    getUserGroups: getUserGroups,
    getUsers: getUsers
  }
})();

app.pageModel = (function() {
  var users = ko.observableArray();
  var userGroups = ko.observableArray();

  function getUsers() {
    return app.data.getUsers().done(users);
  }

  function getUserGroups() {
    return app.data.getUserGroups().done(userGroups);
  }

  function activate() {
    getUsers();
    getUserGroups();
  }

  var vm = {
    users: users,
    userGroups: userGroups,
    activate: activate
  };
  return vm;
})();


var vm = app.pageModel;
vm.activate();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't hard code it like above because the list of groups changes from the server-side.

Comment: yep, understand that, but what you can do is create that hard coded list on the server side so that it gets delivered to the client side, where knockoutjs  can then do something with it.  Now there are a couple of ways that list can get delivered.  It can be rendered on the page as it gets delivered to the client or you can go the ajax/fetch route and query a webapi endpoint to get the data then populate the array.  I will see how I can edit the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Let's try it with AJAX. I wrote an AJAX call and received this back (I'm only showing first in the array): Array[5]
0:Object 
MAMUserGroupName:"MAMGroup1"
__proto__:Object

How would I then map that to my viewModel MAMUserGroups?